# Time Measurement CUDA and C#

Tags: c#, c, visual-studio-2010, cuda

Ich would like to make a comparison how fast my cuda code is on the gpu (data already copied) and how fast my code is on the CPU.

The Measurement in the cuda-code is done as follows

```
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventRecord(start,0);

   //Kernel Execution
    transformKernel7<<<grid,threads>>>(dev_result, width, height, angle, N);

    cudaEventCreate(&stop);
    cudaEventRecord(stop,0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&cuTime, start,stop);
```

Now i want to measure my code the in C#. 
I have following code

```
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

//making some calculation....

var elapsed = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

My Problem is that sw.ElapsedMilliseconds is not precise enough. It gives my 0 for a time of 0.02490834.

I would use ticks but I'm not sure how to recalculate ticks to a proper result. The Time in my Cuda-Code can give my values like 0.058938483. Stopwatch is not precise enough.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `StopWatch.ElapsedTicks`, if that is not granular enough do more work in the comparison, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsedticks.aspx, If you want to know how long a tick is look at the `Frequency` property, it varies by system, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.frequency.aspx

Comment: @Silve2611 You should move the second cudaEventCreate() to be before the first cudaEventRecord() to avoid potentially increase the submit latency of the second cudaEventRecord().

Comment: I would advise you create both start and stop before starting the timing operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ElapsedMilliseconds` gives you the integer time that has elapsed.  So you can't get the fractional part through that property.  You need to calculate it yourself.

If you want a more precise time, divide the `ElapsedTicks` by the `Stopwatch.Frequency` to get your time in seconds.  Then convert to the unit of time you want.

```
var elapsedMilliseconds = (double)(sw.ElapsedTicks * 1000L) / Stopwatch.Frequency;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN, Ticks is a long type, and there are 10,000 in a millisecond.  So, you could do that math manually.

Part of your problem with the sw.ElapsedMilliseconds property might be your use of the var data type.  Your output suggests that the var is being compiled as an int.  Define the variable's type yourself and the compiler won't give it the wrong type.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx

Comment: I'm curious how did you infer that the variable is being set as an int? From what I can tell the compiler will set the variable as Int64 (long) since this is the datatype of the right side of the expression.

Comment: Poster said it's a decimal value less than 1, and it is getting truncated to 0.  That sounds like a float begin cast into an int.  What you're saying sounds correct, though.